# for loop with lxml code used for scraping shows 'list index out of range' error but works for 2 instances

Tags: python, loops, lxml

we are python beginners. 
We have a list of links/websites with donald trumps utterances. Every link represents an whole interview/speech,etc. We now want to access those sites, scrape them and create a text file for every link. At the moment our code does that for 2 or 3 of the links but then just shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Lotte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Code\Corpus_create\Scrapen und alle inhalte laden und speichern - zusammengefügt.py", line 79, in <module>
Trump=(tree.xpath('//div[@class="media topic-media-row mediahover "]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a')[item2].text_content())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

we experimented with the index element, tried [0] or even leaving it out. nothing worked. we then tried to run the code with only one link and without the first loop, which works perfectly

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests
import re
Linklist=['https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-briefing-room-border-security-january-3-2019', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-cabinet-meeting-january-2-2019', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-military-briefing-iraq-december-26-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-videoconference-troops-christmas-december-25-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-justice-reform-december-21-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-agriculture-bill-december-20-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-roundtable-school-safety-december-18-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-governors-elect-white-house-december-15-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-governors-elect-white-house-december-13-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-revitalization-council-executive-order-december-12-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-meeting-pelosi-schumer-december-11-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bill-signing-genocide-december-11-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-chanukah-evening-reception-december-6-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-chanukah-afternoon-reception-december-6-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-china-xi-buenos-aires-december-1-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-germany-merkel-december-1-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-usmca-mexico-canada-buenos-aires-november-30-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-argentina-macri-november-30-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-morrison-australia-november-30-2018', 'https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-trilat-japan-india-abe-modi-november-30-2018']


for item in Linklist:
    headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(item, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


#loads everything trump said

    Text=[]
    for item2 in range(len(tree.xpath('//div[@class="media topic-media-row mediahover "]'))):
        Trump=(tree.xpath('//div[@class="media topic-media-row mediahover "]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a')[item2].text_content())
        Text.append(Trump)

    print(Text, '\n')
```

we want only trumps utterances from every link

Comment: Presumably on the third link https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-military-briefing-iraq-december-26-2018 the div[3]/div/div[2]  indexes don't work. Print out the data you are blindly assuming has that number of divs nested in that way and check that it is as you expect, or not. Full marks for a good MCVE, but nul points for debugging.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
  @barny already gave you the straightforward technique.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips :) we actually made a mistake in the div structure and after changing it to /div[3]/div/div/a it worked out perfectly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your script.

*code.py*:

```py
from lxml import html
import requests
import re
from pprint import pprint


url_list = [
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-briefing-room-border-security-january-3-2019",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-cabinet-meeting-january-2-2019",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-military-briefing-iraq-december-26-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-videoconference-troops-christmas-december-25-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-justice-reform-december-21-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-agriculture-bill-december-20-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-roundtable-school-safety-december-18-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-governors-elect-white-house-december-15-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-governors-elect-white-house-december-13-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-revitalization-council-executive-order-december-12-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-meeting-pelosi-schumer-december-11-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bill-signing-genocide-december-11-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-chanukah-evening-reception-december-6-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-chanukah-afternoon-reception-december-6-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-china-xi-buenos-aires-december-1-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-germany-merkel-december-1-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-usmca-mexico-canada-buenos-aires-november-30-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-argentina-macri-november-30-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-bilat-morrison-australia-november-30-2018",
    "https://factba.se/transcript/donald-trump-remarks-trilat-japan-india-abe-modi-november-30-2018"
]

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"
}

media_row_xpath_marker = '//div[@class="media topic-media-row mediahover "]'
normal_xpath_marker = media_row_xpath_marker + "/div[3]/div/div[2]/a"
movieless_xpath_marker = media_row_xpath_marker + "/div[3]/div/div/a"

xpath_markers = [
    normal_xpath_marker,
    movieless_xpath_marker,
]


for url_index, url in enumerate(url_list):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    lines = []
    media_row_list = tree.xpath(media_row_xpath_marker)
    if media_row_list:
        for xpath_marker in xpath_markers:
            post_list = tree.xpath(xpath_marker)
            if post_list:
                lines = [item.text_content() for item in post_list]
                break
    #pprint(lines)
    print("URL index: {0:02d} - Article count: {1:03d}".format(url_index, len(lines)))
```

**Notes**:

- The problem is that the **3<sup>rd</sup>** *URL* is a little bit different than the others, if you look at it it doesn't have the *YouTube*, so the *xpath* didn't match. That combined with the lack of empty list test yielded the above exception. Now, 2 patterns are being attempted:

  - *movieless_xpath_marker* - which will work for the "faulty" page
  - *normal_xpath_marker* - which will work on the rest of them (this is the 1<sup>st</sup> one attempted)

  When one pattern triggers some results, simply ignore the rest (if any)
- I also refactored the code:

  - Got rid of a loop (and operations uselessly executed multiple times)
  - Variable renaming
  - Constant extraction
  - Code style
  - Other minor changes

**Output** (displaying the article count for each *URL*):

> ```py
> (py_064_03.06.08_test0) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054043232>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> URL index: 00 - Article count: 018
> URL index: 01 - Article count: 207
> URL index: 02 - Article count: 063
> URL index: 03 - Article count: 068
> URL index: 04 - Article count: 080
> URL index: 05 - Article count: 051
> URL index: 06 - Article count: 045
> URL index: 07 - Article count: 014
> URL index: 08 - Article count: 036
> URL index: 09 - Article count: 022
> URL index: 10 - Article count: 105
> URL index: 11 - Article count: 020
> URL index: 12 - Article count: 025
> URL index: 13 - Article count: 028
> URL index: 14 - Article count: 010
> URL index: 15 - Article count: 012
> URL index: 16 - Article count: 015
> URL index: 17 - Article count: 005
> URL index: 18 - Article count: 005
> URL index: 19 - Article count: 006
> ```

Comment: Perfectly good answer, but personally I think it would have been good practice for the OP to have to solve the problem himself.

Comment: @barny: you're right, but I spent quite some time figuring out the pattern for the faulty file (as I'm new to that area), and when it was all done, I felt that it would be a shame not to post it.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for the time invested in our problem . We took some time to understand everything you did but now everything works fine. Especially realizing that the 3rd link has a different structure than the others was very important, so thank you :)